# APACHE https does not work but http works?

Tags: apache, tomcat, ssl, http-status-code-404

SPEC
Apache 2.x
tomcat 6.0
jdk1.6
win os 7

The Load balancing with following config in http works as per worker2.properties file

```
#In httpd.conf

#Karthik

LoadModule  jk_module   modules/mod_jk.so
Include conf/httpd-ssl.conf
LoadModule  jk_module     modules/mod_jk.so
<IfModule mod_jk.c>
ErrorLog "logs/anyFile-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/anyFile-access.log" common
JkMountCopy On
JkMount /* worker1
JkWorkersFile conf/worker2.properties
JkLogFile logs/mod_jk.log
JkLogLevel error
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "
JkOptions +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories
JkRequestLogFormat "%w %V %T"

Alias /WFSSVN  "http://192.168.6.62:8080/ABCD/"
<Directory "E:/JAVA/APACHE22SSL/htdocs" >
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from All
</Directory>
</IfModule>
```

but with SSL certificates deployed and Configurations applied in httpd-ssl.conf

```
#In httpd-ssl.conf

    LoadModule  ssl_module  modules/mod_ssl.so
    <IfModule mod_jk.c>

    ErrorLog "logs/anyFile-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/anyFile-access.log" common

    SSLEngine on
    ServerName ai-itl-107.agilis.com:443
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
    SSLCertificateFile "E:/JAVA/APACHE22SSL/conf/AI-ITL-107.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "E:/JAVA/APACHE22SSL/conf/AI-ITL-107.key"

    JkWorkersFile conf/worker2.properties
    JkLogFile logs/mod_jk.log
    JkLogLevel error
    JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "
    JkOptions +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories
    JkRequestLogFormat "%w %V %T"
    JkMountCopy On
    JkMount /* worker1

    <Directory "E:/JAVA/APACHE22SSL/htdocs" >
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All
    </Directory>
    </IfModule>
```

Note:- httpd.conf has EOF args "Include conf/httpd-ssl.conf"

with regards
karthik
returns 404 error Why ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your open ports with

```
nmap localhost
```

at least 80 and 443 have to be open

Answer (score 0):

I know I've had issues in the past with missing `Listen *:443` directives.  Make sure that somewhere in your httpd.conf file you find the following lines (or something similar):

```
Listen *:80
Listen *:443
```

On some systems those directives are in another file potentially.  For instance, on MAC OSX they are in sites/virtual-host-global.conf.

Hope this helps.